# Wamp server error message: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: port, wamp

Sometimes my wamp starts up with no problems, but it is rare. Restarting my computer sometimes helps. But I need something reliable being at school and learning coding with a server that only works when it wants.

[image: error message]

I wonder if anyone has had this message before and maybe has easy resolution? I have uninstalled Skype and Teams (just in case) but it still doesn't work. Last night it worked perfectly, this morning I'm back to the same error.

I would be grateful for any help! Thank you

I have uninstalled Skype and Teams.

I have reinstalled Wamp twice.

Comment: It looks like you start wampmanager.exe twice, and both instances try to modify the .ini file at the same time. When the error occurs next time, can you check the details tab of windows task manager to see if this process really runs twice? Details of your OS (which windows version) would be helpful to help you better to find out what's going on.
I don't think it has to do with the port, so uninstalling other apps won't help.

Comment: Have you set `wampapache` to autostart at boot time? If you are then manually starting it, that may explain why you seem to have 2 `wampmanager.exe` running

Comment: I'm using windows 10.  At the moment its working, but can't put my finger on the reason why. I uninstalled skype and teams and re downloaded wamp.